# Stop Compression: Google Drive Videos?

Tags: compression, video-editing, google-drive

Is it possible to stop the compression of Google Drive videos?

I uploaded an 18.4MB video in mp4, that was already compressed, and google drive added further compression, resulting in a block effect - only to achieve a further 0.4MB of compression!

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.